# In OpenCV JavaScript code, how can I get the time between frame an acquisition and a processing network message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv

My application both waits on a websocket, and processes images.

When I get a frame from a video file, and even if I wait some time with waitKey(), my websocket server has no processing time to receive any message.

```
while( endRequested != true) {
    let currentFrame = app.videoCap.read()
    // ... Processing image

    // The delay is computed with the native 
    // video frame rate (unit FPS)
    let key = cv4.waitKey(delayWait)

    cap.get(cv4.CAP_PROP_FPS)    
}
```

How can I do the both things together?